# Sending Large file over network/localhost

Tags: android, inputstream, large-files, outputstream

Here's the code:

```
private void sendFile(InputStream file, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "trying to send file...");
        final int buffer_size = 4096;
        try {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
            while(true) {
                int count = file.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                if (count == -1) {                  
                    break;
                }
                out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                Log.d("copystream", bytes + "");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("copystream", "exception caught while sending file... " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to send a large File (InputStream file) over an output stream (OutputStream out). This code works for smaller files, but for something like 5mb and above (I haven't benchmarked the limit), it just freezes after sometime without error or anything.

`Log.d("copystream", bytes + "");` would output for some time, but will eventually stop logging.

`Log.e("copystream", "exception caught while sending file... " + e.getMessage());` never shows.

This is part of a larger codebase which is actually a file server that runs on the Android device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what made it work:

```
while (true) {
  synchronized (buffer) {
    int amountRead = file.read(buffer);
    if (amountRead == -1) {
      break;
    }
    out.write(buffer, 0, amountRead);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Multipart POST. Something like

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, null,null); 
entity.addPart("File", new FileBody (new File(FILE_PATH), MIME_TYPE));
httppost.setEntity(entity); 
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
return response;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is server-side. Also, I'm trying to use the file directly in a video player (it's a 3gp file I'm trying to send). I have seen other android web/file server(s), and some of them actually do have this problem. One that doesn't is kWS, though sadly I can't find the source code for it.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not a server guy, so can't help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask Class for this, here is link for example
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: you can write while loop in doInBackground method of AsyncTask so that OS will assign separate thread to it. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: no. that would spawn me a multitude of AsyncTasks (this loop goes super fast), which would do more harm than good.